# R, text associations with category

Tags: r, text, tm

I have two columns, first one is 'class' (5 categories) and second one is 'Text'. I have managed to load the text column as a vector `corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(data$Text))`

**I ultimately want to reduce the text list in each row to unique terms which correlate to the class.**

```
input=read.csv("input.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
corpus = Corpus(DataframeSource(input))
corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("apple", stopwords("english")))
corpus = tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf, minWordLength=2))
```

When I view the corpus it seems to be ignoring the first column, the 'class' column. I'm looking for code to find which words are highly correlated with the different class categories i.e correlate with class 1, but not the other classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in:

```
corpus = Corpus(DataframeSrouce(input))
```

change it to:

```
corpus = Corpus(DataframeSource(input))
```